# WCF named pipes sometimes not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, named-pipes

I'm using named pipes for communication between 2 different applications on the same computer, both are .NET 3.5 application.

The server is self hosting.

On some machines, users report that it's not working.
When debugging my client trying to connect to the pipe, this is what I found out:

```
There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

I ruled out my client being the culprit as I used the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it resulted in the exact same error when trying to access `net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices` or `net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices/mex`.

Any idea why this is happening? How can I make sure that the endpoint are being created and opened successfully? My server doesn't throw any exceptions.

This is my server's web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" receiveTimeout="infinite"  />
        </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service
            name="MyApp.Client.Core.Managers.WCFClientService"
            behaviorConfiguration="WCFClientServiceBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/MyAppServices/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="MyApp.BL.Interfaces.Service.IWCFClientServiceAPI" bindingConfiguration="NPBinding_IWCFClientServiceAPI">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WCFClientServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does the Server app look like? Is it self-hosting?

Comment: Yes, it is self hosting. I will add it to my post.

Comment: I suspect it is a permission thing.  http://serverfault.com/questions/247064/permission-needed-for-named-pipes-on-windows-2008

Comment: @Blam I think you got it - still testing but it looks like it.